# MySQL's bit type maps to which Go type?

Tags: mysql, go, orm, beego

I used Java before, so some columns' type in database table is `bit(1)`. But now I want to use beego to rebuild my project and I don't want to alter my database table (need do much). I use beego's orm in my project. So which Go type should I use?

Table like this and the deleted column has the question:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| created_time | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| deleted      | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_time | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| icon_class   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mark         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| parent       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

go struct like this:

```
type BaseModel struct {
    Id          string           `orm:"pk";form:"id"`
    CreatedTime time.Time        `orm:"auto_now_add;type(datetime)";form:"-"`
    UpdatedTime time.Time        `orm:"auto_now;type(datetime)";form:"-"`
    Deleted     bool `form:"-"`
}
```

When I use bool in my code, the error like this:

```
`[0]` convert to `*orm.BooleanField` failed, field: shareall-go/models.Category.BaseModel.Deleted err: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "\x00": invalid syntax
```

Comment: First, you should use `BOOL` in MySQL if your type corresponds to a boolean value (as it appears to, based on the name). Once you've made that change, hopefully the answer to your actual question will be obvious.

Comment: But I think  I can't change the type. The old Java program is running now. I'm not sure the old program will run correctly after my change.

Comment: If you're required to use that schema, that sucks, but go with it. But my comment should still help answer your question.

Comment: OK，let me have a try under the test conditon. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Sqlx has created also a custom bool datatype for such situations and it works fine. [Link to related code](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/commit/581097f1be765de629ca6a6e0110d64e98b13267)

```
// BitBool is an implementation of a bool for the MySQL type BIT(1).
// This type allows you to avoid wasting an entire byte for MySQL's boolean type TINYINT.
type BitBool bool

// Value implements the driver.Valuer interface,
// and turns the BitBool into a bitfield (BIT(1)) for MySQL storage.
func (b BitBool) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if b {
        return []byte{1}, nil
    } else {
        return []byte{0}, nil
    }
}

// Scan implements the sql.Scanner interface,
// and turns the bitfield incoming from MySQL into a BitBool
func (b *BitBool) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    v, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("bad []byte type assertion")
    }
    *b = v[0] == 1
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The Scan func can be used as follows;

var valOrg interface{}
var valBB types.BitBool
var val bool
....
err = query.Scan(..., &valOrg,...)
....
err = valBB.Scan(valOrg)
val = bool(valBB)

Answer (score 4):

> So which Go type should I use?

Generally, this depends on how you're using the data more than how it's stored. As you eluded to, you tried using it as a `Bool` (which makes sense) but got an error.

The problem is that MySQL expresses a `BIT` differently than a `BOOL`, and the Go MySQL driver expects a MySQL `BOOL`.  You can fix this by using a custom type that implements the [sql.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface.  Since you presumably have only two (or maybe three, if you count `NULL`) inputs, it should be fairly easy. Note this code is incomplete and untested. It is meant to serve as a guide, not a copy-and-paste solution.

```
type MyBool bool

func (b *MyBool) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    str, ok := src.(string)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unexpected type for MyBool: %T", src)
    }
    switch str {
    case "\x00":
        v := false
        *b = v
    case "\x01":
        v := true
        *b = v
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why Tarmo's solution doesn't work for me. But after a little bit modification, it works.

```golang
type BitBool bool

func (bb BitBool) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return bool(bb), nil
}

func (bb *BitBool) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if src == nil {
        // MySql NULL value turns into false
        *bb = false
        return nil
    }
    bs, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Not byte slice!")
    }
    *bb = bs[0] == 1
    return nil
}
```

In this way, I can do the following

```golang
var isVip BitBool
row := db.QueryRow("SELECT is_vip FROM user WHERE user_id = '12345'")
err := row.Scan(&isVip)
```

```golang
var isVip BitBool = true
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE is_vip = ?", isVip)
```