# How to get MySQL's BIT(64) in golang

Tags: mysql, go

I'm new in go, and trying just read data from MySQL. Schema: "id: INT(11), head: TEXT, filter: BIT(64)"

I tried to do this in common way:

```
type News struct {
    Id      int    `field:"id"`
    Head    string `field:"head"`
    Filter  uint64 `field:"filter"`
}
...
rows.Scan(&item.Id, &item.Head, &item.Filter)
```

and got:

```
Scan error on column index 2, name "filter": converting NULL to uint64 is unsupported
```

I tried some example [with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929480/4443376), but without result.

I tried make own type like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536138/4443376) (really don't understand this):

```
type BitMask uint64
func (bits *BitMask) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    str, ok := src.(string)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unexpected type for BitMask: %T\n", src)
    }
    fmt.Println(str)
    //var v uint64 = 0
    //*bits = v // <- Also have error here
    return nil
}
```

And got similar error: "Unexpected type for BitMask: < nil>"

Comment: Any reason to prefer `BIT` to `UNSIGNED BIGINT`?

Comment: Not sure, not expert in SQL too. Seems like MySQL can make same bit operations with UNSIGNED BIGINT too. If there no any pros except representation, I can change it to int. But BIT exist for some reason, don't want to make mistake for future. And raw queries to SQL will look more understandable for our analytics.

Comment: Possibly, but another guess is that field has to be `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, @tadman, this was a reason. I add `if src == nil {return nil}; str, ok: = src. ([] byte) `in the begin of Scan function and it is work. Remains only to convert the byte array to a number.

Comment: @LynXz maybe you want to use this https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava looks like exactly what I need as base class for `type BitMask sql.NullInt64`. But Scan `BIT` to `sql.NullInt64` not work: `converting driver.Value type []uint8 ("\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00") to a int64: invalid syntax`

Comment: @LynXz you can implement similar custom scanner for Bit Type; Just need to implement 2 fucntions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I make this answer just to close question and summarize result.* So there are 2 ways:

1 Write own type:

```
type BitMask sql.NullInt64

func (bits *BitMask) Scan(src interface{}) error {
  if src == nil {
    bits.Int64 = 0
    bits.Valid = false
    return nil
  }
  buf, ok := src.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return fmt.Errorf("Unexpected type for BitMask: %T\n", src)
  }
  if len(buf) != 8 {
    bits.Int64 = 0
    bits.Valid = false
    return errors.New("Size of bit filed is not 8 bytes\n")
  }
  bits.Int64 = 0
  for i := range buf {
    bits.Int64 *= 256
    bits.Int64 = int64(buf[i])
  }
  bits.Valid = true
  return nil
}
```

2. Don't use `BIT(64)`, but `UNSIGNED BIGINT` instead. Because there are [no advanteges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63953979), only problems. (That is what I'm going to do)